# The simplest way to convert EJB 2.0 project to EJB 3.0

Tags: migration, ejb-3.0, ejb, ejb-2.x

What is the simplest way to convert EJB 2.0 (WebLogic 8.1) project to EJB 3.0 (OAS or WebLogic etc)?
I found just this article ["Converting an EJB 2.0 Entity Bean to EJB 3.0"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vohra-ejb-086603.html), which could automate this process, but forced to do too much manual manipulations.

Comment: xml configured entity and session beans

Answer (score 3):

IMO, you can't really *convert* an EJB 2.1 project to an EJB 3.x project. You can however *migrate* and this is a project by itself. Some more resources:

- [Migrating EJB 2.1 Entity and Session Beans to EJB 3.0](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/04/25/ejb3_migration/)
- [Migrating EJB 2.x applications to EJB 3.0](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2006/jw-0814-ejb.html)

Comment: The second link is broken and I think the correct link is: https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071804/migrating-ejb-2-x-applications-to-ejb-3-0.html

Answer (score 3):

Use Intellij's "Apply EJB 3.0 Style" tool.  It automates a lot of the painful steps, especially replacing ejb-jar.xml configurations with annotations.  Migration can be applied incrementally (you select the ejb's) or all at once.  It does other steps for you as well; details here:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/migrating-to-ejb-3-0.html

I found this to be immensely helpful and worth the price of an Intellij license all by itself for the number of hours it saved me.  I did not find anything comparable in either Eclipse or Netbeans.

An old, but helpful, additional resource:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2006/jw-0814-ejb.html?page=1

Comment: The last link is broken and I think the correct link is: https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071804/migrating-ejb-2-x-applications-to-ejb-3-0.html

Comment: The IntelliJ tool that you have mentioned works only for 2020.1 and prior